# Django 1.8 startup delay troubleshooting

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to discover the cause of delays in Django 1.8 startup, especially, but not only, when run in a debugger (WingIDE 5 and 6 in my case).

Minimal test case: the Django 1.8 tutorial "poll" example, completed just to the first point where 'manage.py runserver' works. All default configuration, using SQLite. Python 3.5.2 with Django 1.8.14, in a fresh venv.

From the command line, on Linux (Mint 18) and Windows (7-64), this may run as fast as 2 seconds to reach the "Starting development server" message. But on Windows it sometimes takes 10+ secs. And in the debugger on both machines, it can take 40 secs.

One specific issue: By placing print statements at begin and end of `django/__init__.py setup()`, I note that this function is called twice before the "Starting... " message, and again after that message; the first two times contribute half the delay each. This suggests that django is getting started three times. What is the purpose of that, or does it indicate a problem?

(I did find that I could get rid of one of the first two startup()s using the runserver --noreload option. But why does it happen in the first place? And there's still a startup() call after the "Starting..." message.)

To summarize the question:
-- Any insights into what might be responsible for the delay?
-- Why does django need to start three times? (Or twice, even with --noreload).

Comment: Had the same problem, downgrade your python3.5.2 to python3.4.4 and it will work just fine. And then rebuild your env.

Comment: @sebb It's nice not to feel alone :-).  Do you have any idea what changed from 3.4.4 to 3.5.2 to cause this? I believe you that making that change made the problem go away for you. But it's too easy for such a change to fix something peripheral to the Python version per se.

Comment: As far as I can know, there is a problem with python3.5, django, and mint. Unfortunetely I do not know what is the problem. Co-worker had also the same problem, told him to downgrade python and all worker out fine.

Comment: Well I just tried Python 3.4.4 on Windows, and it didn't make any noticeable difference in speed. As I noted, from the console, it sometimes runs fast, sometimes slow. Right now, with either 3.5 and 3.4.4 manage runserver is running in 2 secs.  And in the debugger, both run in 25 secs or so.  I haven't tried 3.4.4 on Mint, but with 3.5.2 manage runserver from the console was running < 2 sec. Just in the debugger it was very slow there.

Comment: A particular puzzle is whether the delay, when it occurs is just crunching, or waiting for something, or what.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer.

After some time with WingIDE IDE's debugger, and some profiling with cProfile, I have located the main CPU hogging issue.

During initial django startup there's a cascade of imports, in which module validators.py prepares some compiled regular expressions for later use. One in particular, URLValidator.regex, is complicated and also involves five instances of the unicode character set (variable ul). This causes re.compile to perform a large amount of processing, notably in sre_compile.py _optimize_charset() and in large number of calls to the fixup() function.

As it happens, the particular combination of calls and data structure apparently hit a special slowness in WingIDE 6.0b2 debugger. It's considerably faster in WingIDE 5.1 debugger (though still much slower than when run from command line). Not sure why yet, but Wingware is looking into it.

This doesn't explain the occasional slowness when launched from the command line on Windows; there's an outside change this was waiting for a sleeping drive to awaken. Still observing.